# nodejs http server command res.end() html tag not recognized

Tags: node.js

Just began backend development and got stuck on html tag not recgnized in node js server.

I have an assignment to create local http server.
When using the content type text and json, it works, but with html it doesnt work.

Here is the code

```
const http = require('http');

//CREATE A SERVER wth the HTTP variable
const server= http.createServer(function(req,res)
{
    //headers
    //res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": 'text/plain'});
    //res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":'text/html'});

    //send back the response information
    //res.end("wELCOME TO MY zURI INTERNSHIP SERVER!!!");
    //res.end('{"name": "Miaro the great", "College": " ESPA Vontovorona, Antananarivo", "Occupation": "Technical support engineer turned software developer"}');
    res.end('<html><body style="background:blue; text-align: center; color:orange">
    <h1><marquee>Welcome To THIS CLASS YALL</marquee></h1> 
    <p>HOW'S IT GOING?</p>
</body></html>');
});


//creating a port 
server.listen(4000,'localhost');
console.log("GREAT DUDE! YOU HAVE CREATED A SERVER!!!!");
```

The error is for sure in the function res.end() arguments but I tried '' and "" but nothing works.
Below is an example of error in VS CODE.

```
S D:\dwz\bosyz\zuri\tasks AND RESSOURCES\backend nodejs\wk05\portfolio> node server.js
D:\dwz\bosyz\zuri\tasks AND RESSOURCES\backend nodejs\wk05\portfolio\server.js:14
    res.end('<html><body style="background:blue; text-align: center; color:orange">
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15)       
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)    
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47
PS D:\dwz\bosyz\zuri\tasks AND RESSOURCES\backend nodejs\wk05\portfolio>
```

Tried to change the html tags, the delimiters '' and "", or formatting the texts.

Comment: Seems a simple issue. With `'` and `'` you can not put line feed. If you want to line feed, you should use backtick `.

Comment: Move all the HTML to a single line (string literals in js cannot contain newlines, only template strings can have newlines) and change `HOW'S IT GOING` to `HOW IS IT GOING`. The key to debugging is to remove as many confusing things as possible to understand what's really going on. Now you can figure out how to insert `'` to the string. After you've figured that out and the code still works you can figure out how to make the HTML more readable by splitting it to multiple lines. But at every step make sure you figure it out one issue at a time and make the code work.

Answer (score 0):

Some error at res.end(). I have corrected it. Use backticks instead of single or double quotes.

```
const http = require('http');

//CREATE A SERVER wth the HTTP variable
const server= http.createServer(function(req,res)
{
    //headers
    //res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": 'text/plain'});
    //res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":'text/html'});

    //send back the response information
    //res.end("wELCOME TO MY zURI INTERNSHIP SERVER!!!");
    //res.end('{"name": "Miaro the great", "College": " ESPA Vontovorona, Antananarivo", "Occupation": "Technical support engineer turned software developer"}');
    res.end(`<html><body style="background:blue; text-align: center; color:orange"><h1><marquee>Welcome To THIS CLASS YALL</marquee></h1><p>HOW'S IT GOING?</p></body></html>`);
});


//creating a port 
server.listen(4000,'localhost');
console.log("GREAT DUDE! YOU HAVE CREATED A SERVER!!!!");
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked. I use french keyboard and backtick is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The response should be returned using template literals/ backticks(`) to wrap the html code.

```js
const server= http.createServer(function(req,res)
{
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":'text/html'});
    res.end(
       `<html>
        <body style="background:blue; text-align: center; color:orange">
            <h1>
                <marquee>Welcome To THIS CLASS YALL</marquee>
            </h1>
            <p>HOW'S IT GOING?</p>
        </body>
        </html>`
    );
});


//creating a port 
server.listen(4000,'localhost');
console.log("GREAT DUDE! YOU HAVE CREATED A SERVER!!!!");
```